# bootstrap collapsed toggle on overlay click - doesn't close when clicked away

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to attach a listener that closes the menu when clicked away, so far I managed to do this:

```
$("body").click(function(e){
   var $box1 = $('.navbar-toggle');
   var $box2 = $('.navbar-toggle, .collapsed');
   if($box1.is($(e.target)) || 
       $box2.is($(e.target)) ){
       $('.collapse').collapse("toggle").toggle();
   }else{
        $('.collapse').collapse("toggle").toggle();
   }
});
```

but it's not working, I used hide and show instead of toggle first, but then like a shadow layer was left when clicking the menu button.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Dropdowns close automatically when clicked away (see examples in Bootstrap 2 and 3 docs) so what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: This dropdown doesn't close when clicked away, that's the problem :(.

Comment: There must be a logical explanation why it won't close. Do you see any javascript errors in your console? Can you post the HTML that's creating the dropdown?

Comment: Here the HTML code: https://gist.github.com/gnud/3da879b9712d19935b44, and no js errors, since I was trying all those workarounds, I'm quite sure there aren't any :).

Comment: Hope you already found the solution. If not, you may have to have another look at the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). Aren't you confusing dropdowns with navbars? As you can see in the documentation, the collapse plugin is used for responsive designs (see the example while resizing your browser window).

Comment: the solution was: $('.collapse').collapse('hide'); needed to be added on onClick event for some element intended as overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to use:
$('.collapse').collapse('hide');

attached on the onClick event for an overlay element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap's `dropdown` method, documented here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage.

```
$('.collapse').dropdown('toggle');
```

Comment: and what does that changes, I read that option earlier and tried it, it changes nothing.